# Is it possible to flag an edit for abuse?

Tags: support, flags, edits

There's an overly enthusiastic editor going crazy and editing lots of titles, sometimes changing the meaning of posts.  What's the best way to flag an edit?

Comment: Ladies and Gentlemen, your daily **He Who Shall Not Be Named** question of the day.

Comment: Or at least I sure hope it is the only one.

Comment: Seriously, these questions are getting annoying...If your question gets answered and your able to do your job because of it who cares if a person changed a title??? In the end 99.99% of the edits do not effect the question.  People need to stop getting their panties in a bunch...

Comment: @Miyagi Coder:  Damn straight.  Wax on, wax off, bitches.

Comment: The thing is, the format of the site is not a forum. The questions remain for future seekers to find and learn. So if some freak edits, this is a big problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either flag one of the posts as "Requires Moderator Attention" and explain in the text box that appears when you select that option, or e-mail team@stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 6):

You can always flag for a moderator; if needed, flag the post/reply, and just indicate (in the text) which edit you are referring to.

For info, I'm aware of some of the edits in question, and I'm not entirely convinced that they are as destructive/context-changing as you suggest; but if you flag something, we'll look into it. You can also e-mail the team directly (page footer).

Answer (score 5):

I say that every time someone has an issue with something **He Who Shall Not Be Named** has done, they flag for moderator attention or email team@stackoverflow.com instead of posting a new question on the Meta in hopes of stirring up the hornet's nest all over again.

All this is doing is trying to get as many people with axes to grind against **He Who Shall Not Be Named** (whether rightly or wrongly) so that their voices can all sound louder when bounced around the echo chamber.

**Edit**: I would make the argument that constantly posting on the Meta every time you have an issue with **He Who Shall Not Be Named** is pretty childish, honestly. All you are doing is playing the victim card (and I make this out to everybody who makes this exact same type of question, not just the OP of this one) trying to draw even more attention to the situation, which is inevitably going to lead to it causing even more of an uproar.

All you are doing is trying to elicit some type of public scolding/humiliation for **He Who Shall Not Be Named** instead of asking an actual question, and the moderators and the team have been pretty solid in how they choose to deal with these things. **BEHIND THE SCENES**. Airing your dirty laundry out in public is not the appropriate way of handling these situations.