# Add the ability to flag an edit for moderator attention

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, edits, moderation, flags

We can flag questions, answers, and even comments for moderator attention, but we cannot flag a specific edit that has taken place.

For example, take a look at this question's revision history(+ see disclaimer below):
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/4380/list

While viewing the history, it would be nice if there was the ability to flag for moderator attention.  Specifically during edit wars or when any user feels that the edits are unnecessary.  Seeing as how any concern will require "moderator attention" for further action, this seems like a needed piece of functionality.

We can then in turn use the data from flagged edits to potentially identify users who seem to get flagged more than others in proportion to their overall number of edits.  This will help in identifying potential misuse, abuse, etc.

**(+)***I completely picked this one at random and do not know if any one edit deserves to be flagged or requires it...*

---

**EDIT**
I'm fully aware that you can flag a question/answer/comment already and that some feel that is the route to go for flagging edits as well. But we cannot derive from that any sort of useful data to determine if specific user's have their edits flagged more than others. We cannot determine if people are not using the functionality as well as others.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5062

Comment: *bangs head on keyboard multiple times*

Comment: @Kyle: This is not a duplicate.  I am also specifically looking for capturing metrics of this type of thing as well.

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate, but I don't have the rep to re-open, hopefully somebody will address it someday.

Comment: I don't see how this is an exact duplicate either.  Similar, maybe, but not an exact duplicate.  More useful than the linked question.

Comment: @RSolberg: True, it's a feature request not a question, but I think that the answer in both cases is the same. Besides, moderators have stuff that regular users don't see that enables us to identify repeat offenders, and it's unlikely that these metrics would be available to anyone else.

Comment: @Kyle- If the metrics exist, then I would agree that it is a duplicated question.

Comment: Rolled back to the community revision. Don't delete the dupe link, even if you don't agree. That is rude and disrespectful to the mods.

Comment: Rich- I was purely removing my question as it was a duplicate.  It is not rude, in fact I am promoting the other question.

Comment: @RSolberg: I'd say the best way to handle it is to leave the duplicate link at the top and then leave your original text, so that Google is better seeded for people searching for questions on this topic.

Comment: @Pesto: That makes good sense.  I've corrected the edits to follow this pattern.

Comment: Possibly related (2009-03-04): *[The Great Edit Wars](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/04/the-great-edit-wars/)*. There was once an associated (very long) comment thread with additional context, but it seems to have been lost to time. Or was it on *[Coding Horror](https://blog.codinghorror.com/)* somewhere?

Answer (score 10):

Click on the little "Flag" link under the question, select "Requires Moderator Attention", and type in an explanation such as "The edits by $PERSON are $PROBLEM," click "Flag Post."  Done.  We don't need another piece of functionality for this.

Comment: You lose interesting metrics on who is getting flagged on edits though...

Comment: It may not be necessary, but I think it would be a useful addition.  Just like having stackoverflow isn't strictly necessary, but it is useful and handy.

Comment: We need separate functions to flag posts, answers, revisions of posts, revisions of answers, users, and comments.

Comment: If there's a common theme, I'm fairly certain the moderators see it.  In fact, I'd wager a good deal that they do and that they have discussions with such parties.

Comment: @RSolberg: There aren't that many flags as it is, and mods do see that the same names come up over and over.

Comment: McWafflestix: I usually try and remain civil, but that was quite possibly the dumbest thing I have heard today.

Comment: @KyleCronin: I disagree.  I think it's a workaround, but just like a workaround isn't a bugfix, I think this is still a valid request.  The question wasn't about "HOW do I do this", but about adding a functionality that makes it simpler to find problems.

Comment: @TheTXI: you're kidding, right?  You try and remain civil?  Is this a new thing?

Comment: @Kyle: If mods see the same names come up time and time again, has there been any action?

Comment: McWafflestix: Can you point me to a spot where I was not civil and was name-calling and abusive? Just because someone disagrees with you does not make them uncivil.

Comment: RSolberg: If I flag your stuff repeatedly, your name would come up multiple times, but I would imagine that you would argue that action should not be taken against you.

Comment: @McWafflestix: Well one could describe the moderator flag itself as a workaround to handle those cases where the existing mechanisms for handling abuse don't work. Besides, moderators have stuff that regular users don't see that enables us to identify repeat offenders.

Comment: @TheTXI: I'm sure my stuff has been flagged.  I obviously am one of a few folks who is more vocal about concerns on edits, etc.  I've had my fair share of down-votes because of that.  If my actions required moderator attention, I'd hope they'd get involved and request for me to change something and I would fully comply.  To date, that has not happened at all.

Comment: @TheTXI: Okay, sorry.  it's true, you're generally fair and civil.  I don't much like being directly insulted for what I considered to be a relatively straightforward analogy; the point being that while the suggested functionality has a workaround, so does pretty much everything on SO, including SO itself (we could just ask questions on usenet or whatever).  The point is, at some point, SO is useful not because it is something completely new, but because it makes things considerably simpler, reducing the user friction, as I believe the original question would.

Comment: @RSolberg: Funny you should ask, this post has been flagged twice ;-) In all seriousness, you get flags from people that are upset with their question being edited. You get flags from the people that edited that are upset *that it's been rolled back*. In other words, you can't please everyone, but I at least try to find some middle ground where appropriate.

Comment: @Kyle: That cracks me up!  I have no idea why this post would have been flagged twice.  I guess that even being civil about concerns may "offend" someone?

Comment: @RSolberg: as I learned, posting a question about flagging seems to be a great way to get that question flagged...  :-)

Answer (score 1):

This would go well with the request to have a text entry when flagging, so the reasons can be cited.

Comment: You get text entry when you flag something for moderator attention.  It pops open after you select the moderator attention radio button.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I haven't flagged for mod attention yet, I'm glad it'll be there when I do.