# Little bobby tables language excluded from comments and titles?

Tags: discussion

I was just trying to [help a user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22545519/2589202) discover why his sql had injection problems, but adding a comment with `drop` (heretofore known as [d word]) and `table` (heretofore known as [t word]) together gave an error:

```
An error occurred during comment submission.
```

Basically trying to avoid any [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) problems I'd imagine.

[This doesn't happen on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30142/how-to-correct-trivial-mistakes-in-answers), or at least didn't when that post occurred.

I didnt find any immediate examples on SO of users putting [d word] [t word] in the comments, but am pretty sure that I used to be able to do this.

It seems odd that SO would restrict my language in a comment.

Is the sanitation of comments so difficult that it cant allow this?

Are there any other phrases that I should look out for?

Could the error be a bit more specific so that it would be obvious the problem in the language?

EDIT:

Clearly this is a new issue, I just tried to submit this article with [d word] [t word]  together in the title and body and it gave me a generic error.

```
An error occurred submitting the question.
```

EDIT 2:

@Mysticial and I just discovered that it may have something to do with rep.  In which case, what is the rep to be able to put [d word] [t word] into your posts/comments?

Comment: `drop table`... err... no repro here

Comment: @Mysticial wow.. i try it and get an error.  Could it be a rep thing?

Comment: Oh ic... SE trusts me with the power to `drop table`s, but not the OP. ahahaha

Comment: I seriously doubt that SE would have such idiotic input sanitisation anywhere. Are you sure you're not just, say, having intermittent internet problems that caused an AJAX call to fail?

Comment: Something on your end is blocking outgoing requests with possible SQL injection. Overzealous anti virus is likely culprit. Hunt it down and destroy, or at least disable, it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, on my end huh?  That would be crazy, tho not impossible i suppose.  I will try on a virtual machine.

Comment: could you quote the exact comment you tried here (since meta seems fine with it)

Comment: @RichardTingle, thats just it.  Meta isnt fine with it for me.  It might be as Shadow suggests, just some big brother feature of my work's network.  I'm testing that now.

Comment: I wonder, I wouldn't be suprised if your work network stripped it out. I guess give it a try from home (or mobile)

Comment: testing drop table from azure vm

Comment: It is obviously my network.  Thank you @ShadowWizard for the suggestion.  I will ask why my IT guys are so paranoid.

Comment: Cheers @paqogomez glad it's sorted out, even if not solved. :)