# How can I flag an edit?

Tags: feature-request, support, edits, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to flag an edit for abuse?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5062/is-it-possible-to-flag-an-edit-for-abuse)

I came across an answer that was based on a misunderstanding of the question.

I pointed this out to the user who wrote the answer, and instead of updating/removing his answer, he proceeded to edit the original question so it fit with his answer.

To show that I wasn't the one who misunderstood the question, the one who wrote the question confirmed my interpretation in a reply to my comment.

Normally I flag bad behavior, but I don't know how to flag a wrongful edit, anyone else?

If it is not currently possible, maybe it should be?

Comment: Why on earth did you rewrite the question to fit an answer? If the answer was wrong, you should correct that (comment, edit, down-vote).

Comment: I didn't rewrite the question, someone else did, that is what I want to flag

Comment: Ah - my misunderstanding. In that case flag either the question or answer and use the custom reason to explain what's happened.

Comment: ok, thanks, wasn't sure if a moderator would be able to do anything about it

Comment: it is a duplicate, sorry, didn't see that

Comment: I am not sure this is exactly a duplicate, as the answer to this question is slightly different from the one given to the other question. In this case, the OP replied to a comment about the content of the question; there is no need to flag for moderation attention, when the OP (who is already answering to comments for his question) is able to revert the edit.

Comment: why isn't there need to flag? Reverting the edit is one thing, but the other user displayed malicious intent by changing the original question into something else, and should, in my opinion, be reported.

Comment: If that is the first time the user does it, there is no need to flag the question for moderation attention. The revisions done by users are shown in their user profile. If the user keeps doing that, you can flag the question being edited, reporting that it's not the first time he does that; moderators are then able to verify that it is not the first time he does that, and take any decision on what to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The OP is able to revert the edits done in his question; there should not be any reason to flag it for moderation attention when the author of the question can revert the edit, as any user with the privilege of editing any post can do. The OP already replied to your comment; tell him to revert the last edit.

If the OP doesn't know how to do that, you can do what suggested by ChrisF: Flag the question, and (using "other") explain the reason why you are flagging the question.

[image: screenshot]